# ReactJS : Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
class PostIndex extends Component {

    //define state
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    //useEffect hook
    useEffect(() => {

        //panggil method "fetchData"
        fectData();

    }, []);

    //function "fetchData"
    const fectData = async () => {
        //fetching
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/posts');
        //get response data
        const data = await response.data.data;

        //assign response data to state "posts"
        setPosts(data);
    
    }
}


export default PostIndex;
```

please help me, i new learning at react js.
i was about make class name PostIndex, so i change from function PostIndex() to class PostIndex extends Component. and get error from this line
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
could you help me? please. thanks

Comment: You can't use hooks in the class components, [check docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#:~:text=You%20can't%20use%20Hooks,implementation%20detail%20of%20that%20component.) rather use functional component:

`const PostIndex = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  // rest of your code....
}

export default PostIndex;`

Comment: okay im sorry, i was learning, thanks for give me reference

Answer (score 1):

You cant use react class components with react hooks.

So the right solution will be something like this:

```js
const PostIndex = () => {

  //define state
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  //useEffect hook
  useEffect(() => {

      //panggil method "fetchData"
      fectData();

  }, []);

  //function "fetchData"
  const fectData = async () => {
      //fetching
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/posts');
      //get response data
      const data = await response.data.data;

      //assign response data to state "posts"
      setPosts(data);
  }

  return your markup
}
```

Comment: so i can't use class if there is useState?

Comment: Yes, react hooks only works with functional components

Answer (score 1):

You can't use hooks in the class components, [check docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20use%20Hooks,implementation%20detail%20of%20that%20component.) rather use functional component:

```
const PostIndex = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  // rest of your code....
  }

  export default PostIndex;
```

Comment: thank for share new things for me, its so usefull for me

Answer (score 1):

You can't use React Hooks such as useState in class component.
It only works in functional component.
If you want to use state in class component, please follow as:

```
class PostIndex extends React.Component {
   state = {posts: []}; // define state
        .....
   this.setState({
       posts: ['a', 'b']
   }); // set state
        .....
   let temp = this.state.posts; // use state
        .....
```

I hope this will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: thanks for giving me sample code, i will try it

Comment: but can i call fectdata function without useEffect hook?

Comment: Of course, you can call fetchdata function without useEffect hook.
You can use componentDidMount() lifecycle instead of useEffect in class component.